# How to search users in LDAP using LdapConnection object in C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have requirement to search for users in a LDAP directory using C#. I can do it using `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher` as shown in code below:

```
SearchResultCollection sResults = null;

DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry(_LDAPConnectionString);

DirectorySearcher dSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);    
dSearcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(cn={0}))", userName);

sResults = dSearcher.FindAll();
```

But the requirement is to create a `LdapConnection` object using a standard access user (always the same) as shown below. And use that particular `LdapConnectionObject` to search users using username.

```
LdapConnection ldapConnectionObject = new LdapConnection(
                new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(_hostName, _port),
                null,
                AuthType.Basic);
ldapConnectionObject.Bind(accessUserCredential);
```

How do I use the above `ldapConnectionObject` to search for users?

Comment: Take a look at the example of async ldapconnection searcher: http://dunnry.com/blog/2008/06/05/PagedAsynchronousLDAPSearchesRevisited.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer searching using LdapConnection object. So we can use the SendRequest method of the LdapConnection class using the SearchRequest to get search response back. In below example, I have searched the user with uid userName and retreived its DN.

```
ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(
                new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(_hostName, _port),
                null,
                AuthType.Basic
                );

string searchFilter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(uid={0}))", userName);

string userStore = "OU=WebsiteUsers,OU=InternalUsers";

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest
                (userStore,
                 searchFilter,
                 System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree,
                 new string[] { "DistinguishedName" });

var response = (SearchResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(searchRequest);
string userDN = response.Entries[0].Attributes["DistinguishedName"][0].ToString();
```

Comment: But parameter `_userStore`. What is that?

Comment: Also: My (limited) tour of LDAP has told me that the parameter `DistinguishedName` is a default that is always returned. What I saw was that it is a *"noobie mistake"* to include that in your search parameters. I appreciate your code, though! :)

Comment: @jp2code the `_userStore` is the distinguished name of the object at which to start the search from. We can narrow it down as much as we can.
and yeah it was a noobie mistake :) . I removed that search parameter from my code. Thanks :)

Comment: @PShrestha can you please provide an example for _userStore?

Comment: @Żubrówka the example for _userStore is : "OU=WebsiteUsers,OU=InternalUsers". It is just to specify from where the search should be started from.

Comment: This code was very helpful.  Only in my case I could get the DN as response.Entries[0].DistinguishedName.  The Attributes were coming back empty.